# R GDAX-API Delete Request

Tags: r, rcurl, httr, coinbase-api, gdax-api

I am having trouble with `DELETE` requests in R. I have been successful in making `GET` and `POST` requests using the below code. Any help / pointers will be appreciated.

It will require an `api.key`, `secret` & `passphrase` from GDAX to work.

Here is my function:

```
library(RCurl)
library(jsonlite)
library(httr)
library(digest)

cancel_order <- function(api.key,
                         secret,
                         passphrase) {
  api.url <- "https://api.gdax.com"

  #get url extension----
  req.url <- "/orders/"

  #define method----
  method = "DELETE"

  url <- paste0(api.url, req.url)

  timestamp <-
    format(as.numeric(Sys.time()), digits = 13) # create nonce
  key <- base64Decode(secret, mode = "raw") # encode api secret

  #create final end point----
  what <- paste0(timestamp, method, req.url)

  #create encoded signature----
  sign <-
    base64Encode(hmac(key, what, algo = "sha256", raw = TRUE)) # hash

  #define headers----
  httpheader <- list(
    'CB-ACCESS-KEY' = api.key,
    'CB-ACCESS-SIGN' = sign,
    'CB-ACCESS-TIMESTAMP' = timestamp,
    'CB-ACCESS-PASSPHRASE' = passphrase,
    'Content-Type' = 'application/json'
  )
  ##------------------------------------------------
  response <- getURL(
    url = url,
    curl = getCurlHandle(useragent = "R"),
    httpheader = httpheader
  )
  print(rawToChar(response)) #rawToChar only on macOS and not on Win
}
```

The error I get is `"{\"message\":\"invalid signature\"}"` even though the same command will code and signature will work with `GET` & `POST`.

**Ref:**  [GDAX API DOCs](https://docs.gdax.com/#cancel-all)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I took @mrflick's advise and pointed my connection to [requestbin](https://requestb.in/) based on his feedback on a [different but related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47704167/r-httr-get-request-400-error-gdax/47744193#47744193).

After careful inspection, I realized that the my request for some reason was treated as a `POST` request and not a `DELETE` request. So I decided to replace the `getURL` function with another higher level function from `RCurl` for it to work.

```
response <- httpDELETE(
  url = url,
  curl = getCurlHandle(useragent = "R"),
  httpheader = httpheader
)
```

Everything else remains the same. Apparently there never was an issue with the signature.

I have added this function now to my unofficial wrapper [rgdax](https://github.com/DheerajAgarwal/rgdax)

**EDIT::**
The unofficial wrapper is now official and on CRAN.

Answer (score 0):

just a guess as I am not familiar with the API, but perhaps you are missing the 'order-id' ...

look at: https://docs.gdax.com/?javascript#cancel-an-order

Comment: There are two endpoints. One to cancel all and the other to cancel an order. If I was missing the order id I would have had a bad request, not invalid signature.